# Slide horizontally without position absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI to slide between two divs horizontally, using `position: absolute`, but this is making my sticky footer to overlap with them and messing my design. I want to achieve slide between two divs horizontally seamlessly without affecting footer.

```
<script>
$( ".clickverify" ).click(function() {

var hideoptions = {  "direction" : "left",  "mode" : "hide"};
var showoptions = {"direction" : "right","mode" : "show"};

 $( ".step1" ).effect( "slide", hideoptions, 500);  
$( ".step2" ).delay(200).effect( "slide", showoptions, 500);


});
</script>
```

Below is my CSS

```
 .step1,
    .step2 {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .slidecontainer {
      position: relative;
    }

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
 }
```

Below is my sample HTML

```
<div class="step1">
step1
</div>

<div style="display:none" class="step2">
step2
</div>

 <footer class="center footer">
footer
  </footer>
```

*EDIT*

Here is a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vfu2n7dk/2/, reduce the height to see the overflow. Also I don't want to use `min-height`, because it is spoiling my whole site design on desktop.

Comment: can you add a codepen / jsfiddle link for this?

Comment: @Julie : https://jsfiddle.net/vfu2n7dk/2/

Comment: can you explain more what the problem is?  I do think `position: fixed` may be what you want for your footer, but I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: When I view this design in mobile , since slider and footer position i absolute , both are overlapping